# How to implement f(g) == g(f)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, language-agnostic, lambda-calculus

I [answered a question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43862689/633183) and it got my mind thinking about an interesting (to me) puzzle

With the restriction of using **lambdas, numbers, and `+` only** (no `if`, `?:`, or other language features), the goal is to implement some `f` and some `g` such that

```
// contract
f(x) => f'
g(y) => g'
f'(g') == g'(f')

// or more simply:
m(n) == n(m)
```

> Here's what I came up with so far - this code is in JavaScript for the purpose of being able to demonstrate the code in the browser **but answers in any functional language are acceptable** (racket, clojure, ocaml, lambda calc, etc)

```js
// f
const f = x => k =>
  k(y => y + x)

// g
const g = y => k =>
  k(x => x + y)
  
// make instance of each
const a = f(1)
const b = g(2)

console.log(a(b))
// x => x + y1
// should be 3

console.log(b(a))
// y => y + x2
// should be 3
```

I was able to fix *one* half of relationship, but the other side remains broken due `f` and `g` now being asymmetrical

```js
// f
const f = x => k =>
  k(y => y(x))

// g
const g = y => k =>
  k(x => x + y)
  
// make instance of each
const a = f(1)
const b = g(2)

console.log(a(b))
// 3
// should be 3 (OK)

console.log(b(a))
// y => y + x2
// should be 3
```

I know why it's not working but I'm having trouble trying to fix it. Most importantly, if it's not possible, I'd be interested in learning why.

If you come up with a solution that breaks the restrictions, I'm still interested in seeing it ^_^

Comment: you can resolve it by create something like `mayBe monad`. You can use matrix of something like that http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BooleanFunction.html

Comment: If you consider default arguments to be part of *lambdas*, instead of *"other language features"*, you could do: `const f = x => (fn = () => 0) => x + fn();` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes a strong non-unit type system (eg. Haskell, but I try to stick to JS-like syntax here).

If we stay in the realm of parametricity, we don't need (and cannot even use) numbers or conditions.  The constant functions don't change anything, so I'll leave them out and deal with `f` and `g` directly.

First, observe that the equation

```
f(g) == g(f)
```

implies that both `f` and `g` have function types. Assuming both have different inputs we get that `f: A -> X` and `g: B -> X == (A -> X) -> X == ((B -> X) -> X) -> X == ...`, ie., you get an infinite type.  I remember having read a paper about this exact construction (one can represent it as a pair of types, and I think it forms a category), but unfortunately forgot its name -- maybe there's more to say here.

A simpler solution would be to require `A == B`. Then `f, g: A -> X`, but since `X == A` by the symmetry equation, it follows that `f, g: A -> A` -- for arbitrary `A`, that is.  One possibilitity fulfilling this is the identity function:

```
id(id) == id(id)
```

The other solutions arise when we specialize `A` to `A -> A`; then we search for functions of type `(A -> A) -> (A -> A)`.  These are, for one, the (specialized) identity function, which has already been found, but also all functions of the shape `h => h o ... o h` -- compositions (`(o) = h => x => h(h(x))`) of a function for a number of types.  These "add their repetitions" on application, e.g.

```
(h => h o h)(h => h o h) == (h => h o h) o (h => h o h)
                         == h => h o h o h o h.
```

From this we see that we can choose

```
f == g == h => h,
f == g == h => h o h,
f == g == h => h o h o h,
f == g == ...
```

which are, I think, all functions of type `forall A. (A -> A) -> (A -> A)` (excluding nontermination).

There also seems to be a relation of the limit of this construction (infinite composition) to the infinite case mentined above (now in real Haskell):

```
Prelude> let g = \h -> h . g

<interactive>:11:19:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b ~ (b -> c) -> c
```

Comment: very good explanation re: infinite types – this makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I've been able to get but it does use a ternary (`?:`) expression

```js
const f = x => g =>
  g === undefined ? x : g() + x
  
const g = y => f =>
  f === undefined ? y : f() + y

const a = f(1)
const b = g(2)

console.log(a(b)) // 3
console.log(b(a)) // 3
```

Here `f` is completely equivalent to `g` and we could easily just use one or the other

```js
const f = x => g =>
  g === undefined ? x : g() + x

const a = f(1)
const b = f(2)

console.log(a(b)) // 3
console.log(b(a)) // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to happen obviously both `f` and `g` has to accept a function as an argument and return a same type value. However after tinkering a while it quickly strike me that i am dealing with infinite types.

Well unless your functions are Haskell's `id` like JS's `x => x`. So in Haskell i would do;

```
f :: a -> a
g :: a -> a

f = id
g = id

*Main> f(g)(+3) 2
5
*Main> g(f)(+3) 2
5
```

Can simply be implemented in JS as well.